# Having trouble in getting page source with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get the HTML source of a web page using beautifulsoup.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import urllib.request
sourceUrl='https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/planing-a-trip-from-karachi-to-lahore-by-road-in-feb-2017/414115/2.html'
source=urllib.request.urlopen(sourceUrl).read()
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I want the HTML source of the page. This is what I am getting now:

```
'ps.store("siteSettings", {"title":"PakWheels Forums","contact_email":"sami.ullah@pakeventures.com","contact_url":"https://www.pakwheels.com/main/contact_us","logo_url":"https://www.pakwheels.com/assets/logo.png","logo_small_url":"/images/d-logo-sketch-small.png","mobile_logo_url":"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'
```

Comment: If you need the raw source, you don't need `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: I need HTML source not the raw source

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: use `import urllib2`, then `source=urllib2.urlopen(sourceUrl).read()` will give you the HTML source you want.

Comment: Alternatively, as you have already imported `requests` you could also use that to get your HTML source code: `requests.get(sourceUrl).text`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this code:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_1 = "http://www.google.com"
page = request.urlopen(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Import everything you need correctly. Read [this](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1).