# Extract the source code of this page using Python (https://mobile.twitter.com/i/bookmarks)

Tags: python, python-2.7

how  Extract the source code of this page using Python (https://mobile.twitter.com/i/bookmarks) !

The problem is that the actual page code does not appear

```
import mechanicalsoup as ms
Browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()

Browser.open("https://mobile.twitter.com/login")
Browser.select_form('form[action="/sessions"]')
Browser["session[username_or_email]"] = 'email'
Browser["session[password]"] = 'password'
Browser.submit_selected()

Browser.open("https://mobile.twitter.com/i/bookmarks")
html = Browser.get_current_page()
print html
```

Answer (score 1):

Use BeautifulSoup.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_1 = "http://www.google.com"
page = request.urlopen(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup.prettify())
```

From this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43290890/11034096

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
It looks like the issue is that Twitter is trying to use a JS redirect to load the next page. JS isn't supported by mechanicalsoup, so you'll need to try something like selenium.

---

The html variable that you are returning is actually a BeautifulSoup object and not the text HTML. I would try using:

```
print(html.text())
```

to see if that will print the HTML directly.

Alternatively, from the BeautifulSoup documentation you should be able to use the [non-pretty printing](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing) of:

```
str(html)
```

or

```
unicode(html.a)
```

Comment: It's related that I can not get the real page but show me 404

Comment: I want to get tweets that are in my favorites

Comment: So the main issue is that it's giving you a page not found error rather than it's not printing the code?

Comment: Yes, that's what you get : <a href="/i/bookmarks">use this link</a>